# Alfred van der Poorten--rational functions paper

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, special-functions

Does anybody has a copy of the following paper: 
Alfred van der Poorten, Some facts that should be better known, especially about rational functions; Number Theory and Applications”, Richard A. Mollin (ed.), Kluwer Academic Publishers, Dordrecht, 1989?

Answer (score 7):

Please let me know whether this [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20150331161830/http://maths.mq.edu.au/~alf/www-centre/alfpapers/a085.pdf) works.

Comment: The link does work.

Comment: The standard way to thank someone for an answer here, Sam, is to click in the check mark next to the answer, indicating that you "accept" the answer.